# I want to read an excel and write into a text so that my first cell will be a key and remaining cell are values

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using apachePOI to read excel file and I want to write it in such a way that my header will be a text file name and it will iterate to each cell to generate a new file with a header name.

I have tried but not getting a way how to do it.

```
public static final String FILE_PATH = "C:\\Temp\\rest\\p.xlsx";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
    String value = null;
    String key = null;
    Cell keyCell = null;
    Workbook workbook = null;
    Cell valueCell = null;
    try {
        workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(FILE_PATH));
    } catch (EncryptedDocumentException | org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Map<String, String> data = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator<Sheet> sheetIterator = workbook.sheetIterator();

    while (sheetIterator.hasNext()) {
        Sheet sheet = sheetIterator.next();
        System.out.println("------------ " + sheet.getSheetName() + "-------------");
    }

    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();

        valueCell = row.getCell(1);

        keyCell = row.getCell(0);

        key = keyCell.getStringCellValue() + "---------";

        value = valueCell.getStringCellValue().trim() + "\n";

        data.put(key , value );
        for (String s : data.keySet()) {

            String v= data.get(s);
            System.out.println(v);

        }

    }



    File file = new File(args[0] + filename+ ".txt");

    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);

    printWriter.write(data.toString());

    workbook.close();

    printWriter.close();

}
```

Excel File:

```
Key  fnm    lnm
1    john   xyz
2    sid    poi
```

expected result:
fnm.txt-

```
Key  fnm   
1    john   
2    sid
```

lnm.txt-

```
Key     lnm
1       xyz
2       poi
```

Comment: if I'm understanding what you need you are trying to generate a txt file for each column (except for the first that is the key), right? what problem do you have? what you obtain?

Comment: i want to create a loop so that key (first column)is always there and values will generate one by one from each column and print it to text as header will be a text file name.

Comment: like first file will create as a fnm.txt  and print and same for each column-                                                                   
Key  fnm   
1    john   
2    sid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this following way:

First collect the column headers in a map where key is column index and value is header text. The column header texts will be the file names then. And since first column is always needed in all files, we use `TreeMap` because of the `firstEntry` method which can be used then.

Then collect the column values in a map where key is column index and value is a list of the values in that column.

Now we have all data and can write out it into files. For this for each column in column headers map higher than first column do creating a file named same as the column header text. Then write column headers from first column and this column. Then write in line by line all column values of first column together with column values of this column.

Code:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.util.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

class GetDataFromExcel {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelExample.xlsx"));

  DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
  FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  int headerRowNum = sheet.getFirstRowNum();

  // collecting the column headers
  TreeMap<Integer, String> colHeaders = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
  Row row = sheet.getRow(headerRowNum);
  for (Cell cell : row) {
   int colIdx = cell.getColumnIndex();
   String value = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell, formulaEvaluator);
   colHeaders.put(colIdx, value);
  }

System.out.println(colHeaders);

  // collecting the column values
  Map<Integer, List<String>> colValues = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
  for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : colHeaders.entrySet()) {
   int colIdx = entry.getKey();
   List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
   for (int r = headerRowNum + 1; r <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); r++) {
    row = sheet.getRow(r); if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(r);
    Cell cell = row.getCell(colIdx); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(colIdx);
    String value = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell, formulaEvaluator);
    values.add(value);
   }
   colValues.put(colIdx, values);
  }

System.out.println(colValues);

  // printing it to files
  Map.Entry<Integer, String> firstColEntry = colHeaders.firstEntry();
  Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry = colHeaders.higherEntry(firstColEntry.getKey());
  while (entry != null) {
   String fileName = "./" + entry.getValue() + ".txt";
   PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File(fileName));
   String firstValue = firstColEntry.getValue();
   String value = entry.getValue();
   writer.println(firstValue + "\t" + value);
   List<String> firstValues = colValues.get(firstColEntry.getKey());
   List<String> values = colValues.get(entry.getKey());
   int rowCount = (firstValues.size() > values.size())?firstValues.size():values.size();
   for (int r = 0; r < rowCount; r++) {
    firstValue = (firstValues.size()>r)?firstValues.get(r):"";
    value = (values.size()>r)?values.get(r):"";
    writer.println(firstValue + "\t" + value);
   }   
   writer.close();  
   entry = colHeaders.higherEntry(entry.getKey());
  }

  workbook.close();
 }
}
```